# how to access the GUI class attributes from a different class?

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface

i want to access the text field defined in the MyApp class to write in it 'step 2' from MyThread class  def run(self):
somethin like that :

self.text.insert(1.0,"Step Two")

code:

```
import threading
import time
from Tkinter import *


class MyThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(5)
        #i want to access the text here

class MyApp(Frame):


    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.my_widgets()

    def my_widgets(self):
        self.grid()

        self.my_button = Button(self, text="Start my function",
                                          command=self.my_function)
        self.my_button.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.text = Text(self, width = 60, height = 5, wrap = WORD)
        self.text.grid(row = 10, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)

    def my_function(self):
        self.text.insert(1.0,"Step one") 

        mt = MyThread()
        mt.start()


root = Tk()
root.title("Client")
root.geometry("500x500")
app = MyApp(root)

root.mainloop()
```

i am not very familiar with threading so any help would be apreciated

@abarnet Using your answers down i did this but the GUI is not responding while it is waiting for connection

```
from Tkinter import *
from mtTkinter import *
import socket
import sys


class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):

        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):

        self.submit_button = Button(self, text='start', command = self.my_function)
        self.submit_button.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W)

        self.text = Text(self, width = 60, height = 5, wrap = WORD)
        self.text.grid(row = 10, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)

    def my_function(self):

        mt = MyThread()
        mt.start()


class MyThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)


    def start(self):
        app.text.insert(6.0,'server started')
        app.text.update_idletasks()

        app.text.insert(6.0,'\n'+'waiting for client')

        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.s.bind(('',1090))
        self.s.listen(1)



        self.sc, address = self.s.accept()
        address = str(address)

        self.instruction = Label(self, text = 'got connection from '+address)
        self.instruction.grid(row=7, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)
        self.instruction.update_idletasks()

        msg = self.sc.recv(1024)
        s=msg.find('.')
        g=msg[s:]
        i=1
        f = open('file_'+ str(i)+g,'wb') #open in binary
        i=i+1
        while (True):       
            l = self.sc.recv(1024)

            while (l):

                f.write(l) 
                f.flush()
                l = self.sc.recv(1024)
        f.close()    

        self.sc.close()

        self.s.close()


root = Tk()
root.title("Server")
root.geometry("500x250")
app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your new problem is simple; you just mixed up `Thread.start` and `Thread.run`. See my edited answer for the full details.

Comment: it worked just fine thanks.
if i want to add another button in the GUI class that executes a command in MyThread class what should i do
i want to press a button to close the socket i.e to execute the command self.sc.close

Comment: If you want to control the worker thread from the main thread in any way, you need some kind of synchronization or messaging. But that's really a new question, and definitely too hard to explain in a comment field, so please open a new question about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tkinter is not thread-safe. This means that you cannot access Tkinter objects from another thread.

There are a variety of ways around this, but I think the simplest is to just create a plain old string, protected by a lock, and copy the `Text`'s contents into that variable whenever it changes.

In your code, you've just got a static `Text` object that you write into in well-defined places, which makes this easy. If it were changing dynamically, you'd either want to bind an event, or attach a `StringVar` and `trace` it, but let's keep things simple here.

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(5)
        with app.text_lock:
            text_value = app.text_value

class MyApp(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.text_value = ''
        self.text_lock = threading.Lock()
        self.my_widgets()

    def my_widgets(self):
        # ...

    def my_function(self):
        self.text.insert(1.0,"Step one")

        with self.text_lock:
            self.text_value = "Step one" + self.text_value
        # ...

# ...
```

---

A different option is to use [`mtTkinter`](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/mtTkinter), which gives you a thread-safe Tkinter by intercepting all GUI methods and passing them through a queue. If you don't understand what that means, it's magic. Your `MyThread.run` method can just access `app.text` the same way code in the main thread could.

---

Also, it's worth noting that your code probably doesn't really have any good reason to use threads.

If you want some code to run in about 5 seconds, instead of creating a thread to sleep for 5 seconds, just ask Tkinter to run it in about 5 seconds:

```
class MyApp(Frame):
    # ...

    def my_function(self):
        self.text.insert(1.0,"Step one") 

        self.after(5000, self.my_thing_to_do_later)

    def my_thing_to_do_later(self):
        # same code you would put in MyThread.run, but now
        # you're on the main thread, so you can just access 
        # self.text directly
```

Of course, like any other event handler, if the stuff you want to do after 5 seconds takes a long time or needs to block or whatever, this won't work. But I doubt that's the case with your code.

---

In the new version of your code, you almost got everything right, except for one thing:

You put your background thread function in `MyThread.start` instead of `MyThread.run`.

As [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects) says:

> No other methods (except for the constructor) should be overridden in a subclass. In other words, only override the `__init__()` and `run()` methods of this class.

The default `start` method is a function that starts a new thread, and that new thread then executes `self.run()`. So, if you override `self.run`, whatever you put there gets run in the background thread. But if you override `start`, instead of creating a new thread, it does whatever you implemented there—which, in your case, is a blocking function.

So, just rename `start` to `run`, and everything works.

---

As a side note, one thing that helps me to see whether I've accidentally blocked the main thread is to add a little clock in the corner. For example, in `App`, add this method:

```
def update_clock(self):
    self.clock.configure(text=time.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
    self.after(1000, self.update_clock)
```

Then, at the end of `create_widgets`, add these lines:

```
self.clock = Label(self)
self.clock.grid(row=2, column=1)
self.update_clock()
```

Comment: thanks alot but it mtTkinter available already or should i install it first

Comment: if i want to get values from entries in the gui class to the other class what should i do

Comment: You have to install mtTkinter; it's not built in to Python.

Comment: I don't understand your second comment. But… except for GUI objects, you can share _anything_ between threads the same way I shared `text_value`. You just need a `Lock()` that everyone always grabs when modifying or accessing the variable, and other than that it's the same as using the variable in a single thread.

Comment: what should i do after insatlling it, how to access the text field then

Comment: this is a demo code but in the method run(self):there will be a code that takes inputs from the GUI and be in while loop so that is why i want them to be in a diff thread to avoid GUI freeze

Comment: @MohamedShafie: As I already said in the answer, if you just import and use `mtTkinter` instead of `Tkinter`, you can just access `app.text` from any thread. For the other part… you can turn the `while` loop into a function that just calls `self.later` to schedule the next iteration, and you don't need a thread.

Comment: app.text is in your way around it answer. but i dont have it in my code

Comment: @MohamedShafie: Sure you do. `app = MyApp(root)`. So it's a `MyApp` instance, which means it's gone through `MyApp.__init__`, which means it's gone through `MyApp.my_widgets`, which means it's hit `self.text = Text(self, width = 60, height = 5, wrap = WORD)` which means it has a `text` member.

Comment: self.port = Entry(self)
self.port.grid(row=1, column = 3, sticky = W) if i have this in MyApp.my_widgets. ia can get tha data entered to it by tha same way port = app.port.get() ?